# I can't verify object after json_decode()

Tags: json, laravel, validation, vuejs2, form-data

```
 blog:{
        postTitle: '',
      }
```

this is in JS

```
   let data = new FormData();
   const blog = JSON.stringify(this.blog);
   data.append('blog',blog);
```

Laravel

```
    $blog = json_decode(request('blog'));
    $blog->validate([
        'blog.postTitle' => 'required'
    ]);
```

I have tried to:
after I decode it I have tried to:

```
return $request['blog']
```

and it works.

Error for validation I get is:

```
Call to undefined method stdClass::validate()
```

Comment: `json_decode` returns a `stdClass` Object, which does not have a `validate` method. You should be able to do that `->validate()` on the `request()`, like `request()->validate([...])`, but you cannot run it against `$blog` as you have it defined.

Comment: Well I can't verify `request()` because it is a string, 
and if I don't stringify i get this: `data: "[object Object]"`

And now i have tried this:  `Object.entries(this.blog).forEach(([key, value]) => data.append(key,value));`

and i get: `data: ""`

Comment: I have got it, thanks.

Comment: Is it ok if I don't stringify blog data before i send it to API?

Comment: If you upload it as an array instead of a JSON Object, it would work with the `.` syntax: `blog['postTitle'] = 'Whatever'`, then `request()->validate(['blog.postTitle' => 'required'])` would work properly. Not 100% sure the syntax of that from your JS request though.

Comment: I have tried required it works , min:2  also works, so think I all of the rules are working.

I don't understand this part:
Not 100% sure the syntax of that from your JS request though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sending blog object(without `JSON.stingify()`), and now validation works.

```
 await this.setCreatePost({data, blog})


   request()->validate([
        'blog.postTitle' => 'required|max:100|string',
        'blog.sectionTitles.*.title' => 'required|string|max:100',
        'blog.sectionTitles.*.belongsTo' => 'required|integer|max:1',
        'blog.textareas.*.text' => 'required|string|max:500',
        'blog.textareas.*.belongsTo' => 'required|integer|max:1',

    ]);
```